# Cannot insert duplicate key in object - How to create composite key in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a requirement to create `composite` key using `Entity Framework Core`

This is my class

```
public partial class MasterType
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `Configuration` class, which help me to create `composite` properties

```
public class MasterTypeConfigurations : BaseEntityConfigurations<MasterType>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MasterType> builder)
    {
       base.Configure(builder); 
       // composite key
       builder.HasKey(c => new { c.Id, c.Name});
    }
}
```

I am using `migration` feature of entity framework core

Here is the generated migration script

```
  migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "MasterTypes",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_MasterTypes", x => new { x.Id, x.Name });                 
            });
```

But, when I execute the insert `SQL`, I get error

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[MasterTypes] ([Id] ,[Name]) VALUES  ('CA8301','Type1')
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[MasterTypes] ([Id] ,[Name]) VALUES  ('CA8301','Type2')
```

> Cannot insert duplicate key in object.  The duplicate key value is (C8301, C8301).

Why it's not combining the `Name`. Because `Name` is `uniqie`

Comment: I would think that if you were indeed trying to insert the same record twice, the error you'd receive should be "The duplicate key value is ('CA8301', 'Type1')" and not "...(C8301, C8301)".  Are you sure that the sql script you're using for inserting is correct?  But otherwise, I'd go into the database created (if you have access) and check what the primary key situation is there, just to make sure that it is what you (and EF) expect it to be.

Comment: does we require all the columns to be primary key before joining them in composite key?

Comment: No sorry, meant *key situation, not primary key.

Answer (score 2):

this tutorial based from on this article:[Composite Keys](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/key-attribute)

Entity Framework Core supports composite keys - primary key values generated from two or more fields in the database. However, unlike in previous versions of Entity Framework, you cannot use the Key attribute to define composite keys. This can only be done via the Fluent API.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db=new SampleContext())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
            db.MasterTypes.Add(new MasterType()
            {
                Id = "CA8301",
                Name = "Type1"
            });
            db.MasterTypes.Add(new MasterType()
            {
                Id = "CA8301",
                Name = "Type2"
            });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MasterType> MasterTypes { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MasterType>()
            .HasKey(o => new { o.Id, o.Name});
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}

public class MasterType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The table is designed according to your request:

[image: design of table]

the data based on your question:

[image]

Comment: Issue was in my class. After removing [Key] attribute it started working!